# Querying MySQL database and storing an entire column in a ArrayList

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, jdbc, arraylist

I am making a simple login form, where I will query the database for the user and passwords and save all of them(this may not be the best/safest way to do that, but Im still learning and I dont want advanced code) in arraylists, to then be able to compare them by using the index of them(if the index is the same, then it will associate as same account). I can get the query to work, but I cant store the row value, one by one, in a list... With my code i can login with the very first account, but the others dont work. Can someone explain me how to do this(try not to give ready code right away, I wanna learn).

Answer (score 0):

Hey you look to be a newbie to java if i am not wrong, here is the series of steps that you need to follow to extract all users and their passwords from Mysql database.

```
Step-1  Establish the connection with your databases and table.
Step-2  Use the ResultSet interface of JDBC API to query the database for users and thier passwords.
Step-3  Get the users from ResultSet and put it into one arrayList called User using the add method of arraylist as:- arraylistobj.add(user).
Steps-4 Now Get the passwords from resultSet into second arrayList called Passwords using the add method arraylistobj.add(password).
Steps-5 As you mentioned you want to compare arraylist objects here is a Sample code:

   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
     for (int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++) {
         // compare list.get(i) and list.get(j)
    }
 }

Instead of using two arraylist's one for storing users from database and other for storing passwords,
it is much better to use Maps if you are familiar with as the store data in key value pair, 
in this example user could be the key and passwords could be the values associated with the keys.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what you are trying to accomplish, but take a look at the following example. I would recommend creating a User object that you can store your username and password values in, and create an ArrayList for User. You can use the column index to get the values. Let me know if any questions come up or you have additional criteria.

```
public class DBExample {

private static final String USERNAME = "";
private static final String PASSWORD = "";
private static final String CONN_STRING = "";

private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
}

public static List<User> processQuery(String sql){

    List<User> results = new ArrayList<>();

    try (
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)
    ) {

        while(rs.next()) {
            results.add(new User(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return results;
}
}
```

User Class:

```
public class User {

private String username;
private String password;

public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}